# Search Bar Overlaps Navigation when Resizing Window

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design

I have this page: http://www.bkd.com/industries/private-equity/think-differently.htm. Before I implement this throughout the entire site I want to have it workable when resizing a window, looking at it on a phone or tablet.

When you resize the window or look at in a tablet the search bar is overlapping the navigation words in the gray bar. (Industries, Services, Thoughtware, Client Success)

I am needing it all to stay where it is when the window is resized or when looking at it on a tablet.

I apologize in advance for all the HTML. The navigation was built by a previous employee.

CSS

```
 ul.meg-menu {
 position:absolute;
 padding:0px;
 margin: 0px;
 line-height:17px;


 }
ul.meg-menu li.mgmu {
float:left;


}

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu a.hov1, ul.meg-menu li.mgmu a.hov2, ul.meg-menu li.mgmu a.hov3,  ul.meg-menu li.mgmu a.hov4 {
float:left;
padding: 25px 21px 10px 10px;


}

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd {
display: none;
background:url(/images/common/mdd/mdd-bg.png) no-repeat bottom ;
left:-240px;
padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 77px;
width: 926px;



}

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd ul {
padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd h4 {
padding-left: 0px;
line-height: normal;
margin-bottom:5px;
font-weight:bold;
color: #404040;

 }
ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd h4 a {
color: #404040;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd a {
color: #404040;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd .bd-right {
border-right: solid 1px #cccccc;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd .bd-bottom {
border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd .bd-top {
border-top: solid 1px #cccccc;

 }


ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd a:hover {
color: #b32017;
text-decoration:none;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.hovering div.meg-dd {
display: block;
}

ul.meg-menu li.hovering.mgmu a.hov1, ul.meg-menu li a.hov1:hover { background:  url(/images/common/mdd/services-hover.png) top   center no-repeat;}
ul.meg-menu li.hovering.mgmu a.hov2, ul.meg-menu li a.hov2:hover { background: url(/images/common/mdd/industries-hover.png) top  center no-repeat;}
ul.meg-menu li.hovering.mgmu a.hov3, ul.meg-menu li a.hov3:hover { background: url(/images/common/mdd/thoughtware-hover.png) top  center no-repeat;}
ul.meg-menu li.hovering.mgmu a.hov4, ul.meg-menu li a.hov4:hover { background: url(/images/common/mdd/thoughtware-hover.png) top  center no-repeat;}

.mdd-video {font-size:11px; text-align:center;}
.mdd-video p {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

HTML

```
`<div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="span-8"> <a class="left"  style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin-left: 110px;" href="/"><img src="/images/common/header/logo.png"  border="0"></a> </div>
 <div class="span-0" style="padding:5px 0px 0px 80px">
 <ul style="z-index:2000;" class="meg-menu">
 <li class="mgmu" ><a class="hov1"  href="/services/services.htm"><img alt="Services" src="/images/common/mdd/services.png" style="padding-right:20px" ></a>
 <div class="meg-dd">
 <div style="width:150px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3  ">
 <h4 ><a href="http://www.bkd.com/services/audit-assurance.htm">Audit &amp; Assurance</a></h4>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="/services/assurance.htm">Assurance</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/lease-accounting.htm">Lease Accounting</a></li>
 </ul>
 <h4 ><a href="http://www.bkd.com/services/tax.htm"><strong>Tax</strong></a></h4>
 <ul>
 <li><a  href="/services/accounting-outsourcing.htm">Accounting Outsourcing</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/estate-tax.htm">Estate Tax</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/international-tax-services.htm">International Tax</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/state-local-tax.htm">State &amp; Local Tax</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/real-estate-cost-segregation.htm">Real Estate Cost Segregation</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/research-development-tax-credits.htm">R&D Tax Credits</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/repair-regulations.htm">Repair Regulations</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/transfer-pricing-tax.htm">Transfer Pricing</a></li>
 </ul>

 </div>
 <div style="width:200px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3  ">

 <div style="width:715px"> <h4><a href="http://www.bkd.com/services/advisory.htm">Advisory</a> </h4></div>
 <ul>
 <li><strong><a  href="/services/business-transition-services.htm">Business Transition Services</a></strong>
 <ul>
 <li><a  href="/services/mergers-acquisitions.htm">Mergers & Acquisitions</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/company-sales-divestitures.htm">Company Sales & Divestitures</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/management-buyouts.htm">Management Buyouts</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/debt-equity-financing.htm">Debt & Equity Financing</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/succession-planning-value.htm">Succession Planning & Value</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/recapitalizations.htm">Recapitalizations</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/transaction-services.htm">Transaction Services</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/business-owner-succession.htm">Business Owner Succession</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/exit-strategies.htm">Exit Strategies</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/esop-succession-planning.htm">ESOP Succession Planning</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="width:210px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3  ">
 <br /><br />
 <ul>
 <li><strong><a  href="/wealth-advisors/index.htm">Wealth Management</a></strong>
 <ul>
 <li><a  href="/wealth-advisors/services/index.htm">Financial Planning</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/wealth-advisors/services/index.htm">Retirement Planning</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/wealth-advisors/services/index.htm">Education Funding</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/wealth-advisors/services/index.htm">Estate Planning</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/wealth-advisors/services/index.htm">Investment Management</a></li>
 <li><a href="/wealth-advisors/services/index.htm">Charitable Gift Strategies</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/wealth-advisors/services/index.htm">Benefit Plan Consulting</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/wealthplan.htm">WealthPlan</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/tax-strategies.htm">Tax Strategies</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/services/risk-management.htm">Risk Management</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="width:260px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 "><br />
 <br />
 <h4><a href="/services/employee-benefit-plans.htm">Employee Benefit Plans</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="/services/forensics-investigation-litigation.htm">Forensics, Investigation, Litigation</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="/services/enterprise-risk-solutions.htm">Enterprise Risk Solutions</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="/technologies/">Information Technology</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="/services/international-services.htm">International Services</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="/industries/">Performance Services</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="/services/valuation-services.htm">Valuation Services</a></h4>



 </div>
 </div>
 </li>

 <li class="mgmu"><a class="hov2"  href="/industries/"><img alt="Industries" src="/images/common/mdd/industries.png" style="padding-right:20px"></a>
 <div class="meg-dd">
 <div style="width:230px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3  ">
 <h4 ><a href="/industries/health-care/">Health Care</a></h4>

 <ul>
 <li><a  href="/industries/health-care/community-health-centers/">Community Health Centers</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/industries/health-care/compliance-corporate-integrity/">Compliance & Corporate Integrity</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/industries/health-care/forecasts-strategic-planning/">Forecasts & Strategic Planning</a></li>

 <li><a  href="/industries/health-care/home-care-hospice/">Home Care &amp; Hospice</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/industries/health-care/hospitals/">Hospitals</a></li>
 <li><a href="/industries/health-care/long-term-care/">Long-Term Care &amp; Senior Living</a></li>
 <li><a href="/industries/health-care/operations-clinical-consulting/">Operations & Clinical Consulting</a></li>

 <li><a  href="/industries/health-care/physician-services/">Physician Services</a></li>

 </ul>

 <h4 ><a href="/industries/manufacturing-distribution/">Manufacturing & Distribution</a></h4>

 <ul>
 <li><a  href="/industries/manufacturing-distribution/operations-consulting.htm">Operations Consulting</a></li>

 <li><a  href="/industries/manufacturing-distribution/performance-measurements.htm">Performance Measurement</a></li>


 </ul>

  <h4><a href="/industries/private-equity/">Private Equity</a></h4>
  <ul>
  <li><a  href="/services/transaction-services.htm">Transaction Services</a></li></ul>
  </div>

  <div style="width:210px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3  ">

  <h4 ><a href="/industries/energy/">Energy</a></h4>
  <ul>
  <li><a  href="/industries/energy/exploration-and-production.htm">Exploration & Production</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/energy/oil-gas.htm">Oilfield Services</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/energy/midstream-downstream.htm">Midstream & Downstream</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/energy/utilities.htm">Power</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/energy/vendor-audit-services.htm">Vendor Audit Services</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h4 ><a href="/industries/financial-services/">Financial Services</a></h4>
  <ul>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/de-novo-banks.htm">De Novo Banks</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/enterprise-risk-management.htm">Enterprise Risk Management</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/financial-restructuring.htm">Financial Restructuring</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/internal-audit.htm">Internal Audit</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/loan-review.htm">Loan Reviews</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/profitability-enhancement.htm">Profitability Enhancement</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/regulatory-compliance.htm">Regulatory Compliance</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/strategic-financial-planning.htm">Strategic Financial Planning</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/financial-services/tax-services.htm">Tax Services</a></li>

  </ul>


  </div>
  <div style="width:220px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3  ">


  <h4 ><a href="/industries/not-for-profit/">Not-for-Profit</a></h4>

  <ul>
  <li><a  href="/industries/not-for-profit/foundations.htm">Foundations</a></li>

  <li><a  href="/industries/not-for-profit/membership-organizations.htm">Membership Organizations</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/not-for-profit/religious-organizations.htm">Religious Organizations</a></li>


  </ul>
  <h4 ><a href="/industries/government/">Government</a></h4>
  <ul>
  <li><a  href="/industries/government/airport-transportation-authorities.htm">Airport & Transportation Authorities</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/government/municipal-state-government.htm">Municipal & State Government</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/government/public-power-utilities.htm">Public Power & Utilities</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/government/tribal-government.htm">Tribal Government</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h4><a href="/industries/higher-education/">Higher Education</a></h4> 

  <ul>
  <li><a  href="/industries/higher-education/integraprotect.htm">Managing Reputational Risk</a></li></ul>

  <h4 ><a href="/industries/construction-real-estate/">Construction &amp; Real Estate</a></strong><a href="/industries/construction-real-estate/"></a></h4>
  <ul>
  <li><a  href="/industries/construction-real-estate/architecture-engineering/">Architecture &amp; Engineering</a></li>
  <li><a href="/industries/construction-real-estate/construction/">Construction</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/industries/construction-real-estate/real-estate/">Real Estate</a></li>
  </ul>


  </div>

  <div style="width:180px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 ">

  <h4><a href="/industries/dealerships/">Dealerships</a></h4>

  <h4><a href="/industries/individuals/">Individuals</a></h4>
  <h4><a href="/industries/insurance-services/">Insurance Services</a></h4>

  <h4><a href="/industries/retail/">Retail</a></h4>
  <h4><a href="/industries/service-organizations/">Service Organizations</a></h4>
  <h4><a href="/industries/technology/">Technology & Communications</a></h4>
  <h4><a href="/industries/transportation/">Transportation & Logistics </a></h4>
  </div>
  </div>
  </li>

  <li class=" mgmu"><a class="hov3"  href="/thought-center/"><img alt="Though Center" src="/images/common/mdd/thoughtware.png" style="padding-right:20px"></a>
  <div class="meg-dd">
  <div style="width:240px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3 ">
  <h4><a href="/articles/">Articles </a></h4>
  <ul style="margin-bottom:5px;">
  <li><a href="/articles/industry/"><strong>Industry</strong></a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="/articles/tax/"><strong>Tax</strong></a> </li>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/articles/tax/salt/">State &amp; Local Tax</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/articles/tax/international-tax/">International Tax</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li><a href="/articles/accounting-auditing/"><strong>Accounting & Auditing</strong></a> </li>
  <li><a href="/articles/advisory/"><strong>Advisory</strong></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a  href="/articles/advisory/forensics-investigation-litigation/">Forensics, Investigation & Litigation</a></li>
  <li><a href="/articles/advisory/information-technology/">Information Technology</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/articles/advisory/wealth-management/">Wealth Management</a></li>
  <li><a  href="/articles/advisory/it-risk-services/">IT Risk Services</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/articles/software/"><strong>Software</strong></a> </li>
  </ul>

  </div>


<div style="width:170px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3 ">
      <h4><a href="/webinars/">Webinars </a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/webinars/cre/">Construction &amp; Real Estate</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webinars/fs/">Financial Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="/webinars/government/">Government</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webinars/hc/">Health Care</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webinars/higher-education/">Higher Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webinars/insurance-services/">Insurance Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webinars/md/">Manufacturing &amp; Distribution</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webinars/not-for-profit/">Not-for-Profit</a></li>

        <li><a href="/service/Forensics/institute/index.htm"> Forensics Institute</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webinars/forensics-valuation/">Forensics & Valuation</a></li>

        <li><a href="/webinars/microsoft-dynamics/">Microsoft Dynamics</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webinars/sage-software/">Sage Software</a></li>

      </ul>
      </div>
      <div style="width:150px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 mr-rt-3 ">
      <h4><a href="/blogs/">Blogs</a></h4>
      <ul>

      <li><a href="http://bkdforensics.com/">BKD Forensics </a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.dynamicsgpinsights.com/">Dynamics GP </a></li>
      <li><a href="http://sageerpinsights.com/">Sage ERP Insights </a></li>

      </ul>
      <h4><a href="/videos/">Videos</a></h4>
      <ul>
      <li><a  href="/videos/industry-insights/">Industry Insights</a></li>
      <li><a  href="/videos/market-insights.htm">Market Insights</a></li>
      <li><a href="/videos/technologies.htm">Technologies</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div style="width:280px; margin-left:5px" class="span-0 ">

      <h4><a href="http://pages.bkd.com/SubscriptionManagement_Center.html">Email Subscriptions</a></h4>


      <h4><a href="/events/Calendar.htm">Events Calendar</a></h4>
      <h4><a href="/stay-connected/">Stay Connected</a></h4>
      <h4><a href="/thought-center/speakers-bureau/">Speakers' Bureau</a></h4>


      </div>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li class=" mgmu"><a class="hov4"  href="/client-success/"><img alt="Client Success" src="/images/common/mdd/client-success.png" ></a></li>



      </li>
      </ul>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-top:25px; float:right" class="span-0 last">

      <form action="/search/">
      <input type="image" src="/images/common/search/search-icon-new.png" style=" float:left; outline:none" alt="Search">

      <input type="text" name="zoom_query" value="Search" style=" background-image:url(/images/common/search/search-field-new.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; margin: 0; line-height:26px; height: 26px; width:200px; color:#666; background-color:#fff; border:none; outline:hidden; border-radius: 7px; float:right; padding: 0px 0px 0 10px; margin-left: 0px;" onFocus="this.value=this.value.replace(/^Search$/, '')">
     </form>
     </div>

     <div class="clear"></div>
     <script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
     function addMega(){
     $(this).addClass("hovering");
     }
     function removeMega(){
     $(this).removeClass("hovering");
     }
     var megaConfig = {
     interval: 100,
     sensitivity: 4,
     over: addMega,
     timeout: 100,
     out: removeMega
     };
     $("li.mgmu").hoverIntent(megaConfig)
     }); 


     </script>
```

`

Comment: We don't need your entire code. Post only the code that relates your question.

Comment: If you want a common page layout which fits on desktop as well as devices, you could use bootstrap. Using the navbar in bootstrap would make your job a lot easier. You can see the demo [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) by resizing the window.

Comment: @Vijeth I have never used bootstrap before, is it fairly easy to get going?

Comment: @Vijeth or is there an easier way for me to use what I have already and just make the search bar stay where it is instead of moving over the text?

Comment: @Marcy730 Yes there are lot of tutorials, sample layouts and examples available online to start with. Once you start using you will get the hang of it. And about the existing layout, do you think you can fit all the components of the navigation + search bar on a smaller screen?